# Hiding my UINavigationBar causes my UIWebView to scroll erratically. How can I fix this?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, show-hide

I have a UIWebView that is sandwiched in between a UINavigationController (top) and a UIToolbar (bottom). When the user taps twice on the UIWebView, I want to smoothly animate the top and bottom bars to hide. However, when I use this code (and several other different variations of this concept), the bar hides fine, but sometimes (sometimes not) the UIWebView content scrolls up 20-30px:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

It works sometimes, and then other times it doesn't. I just want to be able to smoothly hide/unhide both bars, changing the UIWebView size to full screen/not full screen as I go.

Anybody done this? Or know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your `UINavigationBar` translucant

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

in your `viewWillAppear` method.